# sending a mail using informatica workflow

Tags: unix, informatica

I have an informatica mapping-a simple one which has `Sq->t(x)->tgt`

Here I am populating the target (which is a flat file) only if a certain condition is satisfied, which is included  in the transformations.

Now my requirement is that if the target (a txt file) is populated even with even one record it should send out an email to two people.

I am using the `mailx` Unix command but I am not sure how to check whether there are any records in the target file using Unix script. This is what I have tried:

```
if [ "/data/informatica/Services/myfolder/TgtFiles/filename.csv" = "1" ]//here i am trying to check if there are any records in the target
then
    mailx -s "Target is populated" "reciepent1@abc.com reciepent2@abc.com "<<ed
    Validation completed
    ed
else
    exit
    eod
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what shell informatica is calling, but this should work with about any bourne derivative (not csh).

```
if [ `wc -l < "/data/informatica/Services/myfolder/TgtFiles/filename.csv"` -gt 0 ]
   # //here i am trying to check if there are any records in the target
then
    mailx -s "Target is populated" "reciepent1@abc.com reciepent2@abc.com "<<ed
    Validation completed
    ed
else
    exit
    eod
fi
```

I can't easily test the mailx part and don't know what `eod` means for informatica. If I replace the `then` body with `echo yep` and the `else` body with `echo nope`, it works as expected.

If you can use newer command-substitution , replace the first line with

```
if [ $(wc -l < "/data/informatica/Services/myfolder/TgtFiles/filename.csv") -gt 0 ]
```

which will set a good example for anyone copying your code.

IHTH.

Answer (score 0):

This can be also achieved using condition on a link prior to `Command Task` in the `Workflow`. You'd need to add the following condition on the link between the `Session` and `Command Task`:

```
$your_session_name.TgtSuccessRows > 0
```

If you're invoking your script using `Post-Session Success Command`, you'd need to change it to `Command Task` first.